# what is the meaning of status value in Kubernetes manifest file

Tags: kubernetes

what is the meaning for "**status:**" in the kubernetes manifest file

```
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "7000"
    port: 7000
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: ams-app
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

See "[Object Spec and Status](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/kubernetes-objects/#object-spec-and-status)"

> Every Kubernetes object includes two nested object fields that govern the object’s configuration: the object spec and the object status.
>
> - The spec, which you must provide, describes your desired state for the object–the characteristics that you want the object to have.
> - **The status describes the actual state of the object, and is supplied and updated by the Kubernetes system**.
>
> At any given time, the Kubernetes Control Plane actively manages an object’s actual state to match the desired state you supplied.

So:

> For example, a [Kubernetes Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) is an object that can represent an application running on your cluster.
>   When you create the Deployment, you might set the Deployment spec to specify that you want three replicas of the application to be running.
>   The Kubernetes system reads the Deployment spec and starts three instances of your desired application–**updating the status to match your spec**.
>   If any of those instances should fail (a status change), the Kubernetes system responds to the difference between spec and status by making a correction–in this case, starting a replacement instance.

In your case, what you mention matches the publication of a [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) of type [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-loadbalancer).

> The actual creation of the load balancer happens asynchronously, and information about the provisioned balancer will be published in the Service’s **`status.loadBalancer`** field.
>   For example:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 9376
  clusterIP: 10.0.171.239
  loadBalancerIP: 78.11.24.19
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 146.148.47.155
```